How to compile sqlite3 source code for debugging in vscode
I have cloned sqlite3 codebase from github and ran following command on folder.
./configure --disable-amalgamation --debug

After that I have ran following command to build
make sqlite3

sqlite3 is building fine. It generates the sqlite3 executable which works fine. I'm having trouble with debuging in vscode, when I try to add breakpoint, vscode is not keeping red point turned on, I feel something is wrong.
This is my launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/sqlite3",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}

This config has worked fine with other C/C++ repos, only this is giving problem.
Can someone please guide me here.
Btw, I'm using Mac m2

From the github repo of sqlite:
./configure --enable-all --enable-debug CFLAGS='-O0 -g'

needs to be invoked.
So not --debug but --enable-debug.
Just tested this on my machine (Ubuntu 24.04.1) and it worked.
